# MySQL Exclude a matching row

Tags: mysql

That is the basic layout of the data I am joining on.

```
+---------+--------------------+----------+------------------------+
| IssueId |        Path        |   Data   |   Actual Create Date   |
+---------+--------------------+----------+------------------------+
|    1234 |  /status           |  Open    |  04/20/2018 16:20:22   |
|    1234 |  /next_step_action |  Comment |  04/20/2018 16:20:22   |
|    1234 |  /next_step/action |  Step 2  |  04/20/2019 17:20:20   |
|    1234 |  /next_step/action |  Comment |  04/20/2019 18:20:20   |
|    1234 |  /next_step/action |  Step 3  |  04/20/2019 20:20:20   |
|    1234 |  /next_step/action |  Comment |  04/21/2019 08:20:20   |
|    5678 |  /status           |  Open    |  04/22/2018 22:20:22   |
|    5678 |  /next_step_action |  Comment |  04/22/2018 22:20:22   |
|    5678 |  /next_step/action |  Step 2  |  04/20/2019 23:20:20   |
|    5678 |  /next_step/action |  Comment |  04/20/2019 23:25:20   |
|    5678 |  /next_step/action |  Step 3  |  04/20/2019 23:27:20   |
|    5678 |  /next_step/action |  Comment |  04/21/2019 23:45:20   |
+---------+--------------------+----------+------------------------+
```

Edit:

I attempted the answer below, it seems to be a never ending query.  So I wrote the following based on it and it seems to work properly:

```
    SELECT
        `IssueId`,
        `Path`,
        `Data`,
        `Actual Create Date`
    FROM
        SIM_FE_Audit_Data a
    WHERE
        `Data` IN ( 'Open', 'Comment', 'Pending Others', 'Work in Progress', 'Resolved' )
    AND NOT
        `IssueId` IN (
            SELECT
                `IssueId`
            FROM
                SIM_FE_Audit_Data b
            WHERE
                a.`Actual Create Date` = b.`Actual Create Date`
            AND
                a.`Data` = 'Comment'
            AND
                b.`Data` = 'Open'
            )
ORDER BY `IssueId`, `Actual Create Date`
```

From that I then added an inner join on the common IssueId:

```
SELECT
    `a`.`AssignedFolderLabel` AS `Folder`,
    `a`.`IssueId` AS `Id`,
    `a`.`IssueUrl` AS `IssueUrl`,
    `b`.`ShortId` AS `ShortId`,
    `a`.`Severity` AS `Severity`,
    `a`.`Title` AS `Issue_Description`,
    `a`.`Request_Type` AS `Request_Type`,
    `a`.`Site` AS `Site`,
    `b`.`Path` AS `Path`,
    `b`.`Data` AS `Data`,
    `b`.`Actual Create Date` AS `Actual Create Date` 
FROM
    SIM_FE a
    INNER JOIN (
SELECT
    `b`.`IssueId` AS `Id`,
    `b`.`ShortId`,
    `b`.`Path` AS `Path`,
    `b`.`Data` AS `Data`,
    `b`.`Actual Create Date` AS `Actual Create Date` 
FROM
    `SIM_FE_Audit_Data` `b` 
WHERE
    (
    ( `b`.`Data` IN ( 'Open', 'Comment', 'Pending Others', 'Work in Progress', 'Resolved' ) ) 
    AND (
    NOT (
    `b`.`IssueId` IN (
SELECT
    `c`.`IssueId` 
FROM
    `SIM_FE_Audit_Data` `c` 
WHERE
    ( ( `b`.`Actual Create Date` = `c`.`Actual Create Date` ) AND ( `b`.`Data` = 'Comment' ) AND ( `c`.`Data` = 'Open' ) ) 
    ) 
    ) 
    ) 
    ) 
ORDER BY
    `b`.`IssueId`,
    `b`.`Actual Create Date` 
    ) `b` ON `b`.`Id` = `a`.`IssueId` 
WHERE
    NOT a.Title LIKE '%test%'
```

Here is the resultant query; now I have to figure out how to create a view from this.  So far it doesn't want to let me, but that is a different question since it will likely require me to re-write everything.

I will award the bounty to Mocking since their answer is like 99% the query for the table.

Comment: Your whete criteria turns the left join into an inner join... apart from this, no idea what you are after.

Comment: The table at top shows a small section of the data where I am trying to remove the duplicate entries.  The system I pull the data from, which I have no control over, goes from Open to Comment at the exact same moment.  Comments can happen again later, but Open only ever happens once.  I need to remove the Comment that happens at the exact same moment as Open from the data and leave the rest of them.

Comment: Share some sample data and your desired results and we can help out. We can't reverse engineer a sql statement to understand your data though. This question will almost definitely remain unanswered until you share more details, bounty or not.

Comment: I am unsure why the table at the top is not enough of an example.  What else do you need?

Comment: How do you determine which row to keep?  Is there ever a case where there will be 3 rows with the same actual date?

Comment: nope, there is only ever two rows with the exact same datetime.   I have never seen an instance where there are 3 in over 400K rows of data.  It is only the first two rows in a given set of data.  I don't think my second query is too far off; I just don't know why it didn't complete in 5 minutes.  I am looking to drop the Comment data when it matches the Open data from the table above.

Comment: How do you determine which row to keep?  it looks like there is other `data` other than `comment`, like `open` and `pending others`.

Comment: I am not sure how I can be more clear; keep everything EXCEPT where Comment matches open.  I literally only want to drop the single Comment line that matches the actual create date of Open

Comment: You need to show us the layout (columns and keys) of both tables and show us some sample data from each one.  It might be common sense to you but we don't know how your tables are set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering this against my better judgment.

```
SELECT `b`.`Path` AS `Path`,
       `b`.`Data` AS `Data`,
       `b`.`Actual Create Date`
    FROM `SIM_FE_Audit_Data` `b`
 WHERE `b`.`IssueId` NOT IN 
       (SELECT `b2`.`IssueId` 
          FROM `SIM_FE_Audit_Data` `b2` 
          WHERE `b2`.`Actual Create Date` = `b`.`Actual Create Date` 
            AND `b2`.`Data` = 'Comment' 
            AND `b`.`Data` = 'Open'
            AND `b`.IssueId <> `b2`.IssueId)
```

This is based on all the information stated by OP as of writing this answer.

I am personally aware that a `Date` should not be used as a key.

Comment: I expanded the table for you, you don't have to use date as the key.  There is a key (which it seems you figured out) which is IssueId.  The reason the other table that is joined doesn't matter is because the table I am worried about I can always create a view and then join on the view if I can figure out how to get the first table to remove the comment that has the exact time stamp as the open.  So far I can't get your answer to work; I let it run for 800 seconds and it didn't seem to have an end in sight.

Comment: I made an edit on my answer.  How many rows are in the table and is it indexed?

Comment: At this time there are about 1500 rows.

Answer (score 1):

I have written this query and tested it.
It gives you the rows as per your requirements.
You can easily delete the required rows by adding unique id.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t1.issue_id as t1_issue_id,
        t1.path as t1_path,
        t1.data as t1_data,
        t1.acd as t1_acd,
        t2.issue_id as t2_issue_id,
        t2.path as t2_path,
        t2.data as t2_data,
        t2.acd as t2_acd
    FROM 
        MY_TABLE_NAME as t1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM 
            MY_TABLE_NAME
        WHERE
            `data` LIKE "Comment"
    ) as t2
    ON
        t1.issue_id = t2.issue_id
    WHERE
        t1.`data` LIKE "Open"
) as t3
WHERE
    t1_acd = t2_acd
```

Here acd stands for Actual Create Date
Hope it helps